# Selenium Webdriver Auto complete Text Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, webdriver

I have been trying to make a registration process in a website, i have user the following script,

```
    package agent;

    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.awt.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.junit.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class TaxRegistration {
      private static final TaxRegistration Driver = null;
    private WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
      private String baseUrl;
      private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
      private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
      private By tagText = By.id("AddressDetails_City");


      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/Vignesh/Automation/New folder (2)/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        baseUrl = "http://govreports.com.au/dev/taxagentt1.html";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }

      @Test
      public void testBASFormWebdriver() throws Exception {
          driver.get("http://govreports.com.au/dev/taxagentt1.html");
            driver.findElement(By.id("BAS")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("TFND")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("PAYG")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("TPAR")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            //((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,2000)");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("OUT")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            //((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,1000)");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("BUL")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("NUL")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("IUL")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            //((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,6000)");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn.btn-default > b")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("AgentNo")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("AgentNo")).sendKeys("78301003");
            driver.findElement(By.id("AgentName")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("AgentName")).sendKeys("Vignesh Check");
            driver.findElement(By.id("SendQuote")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='plancodeTPAR'])[2]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@value='1'])[9]")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@value='1'])[9]")).sendKeys("2");
            driver.findElement(By.id("Proceed")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("ABN")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("ABN")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("ABN")).sendKeys("19087046080");
            driver.findElement(By.id("BusinessName")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys("vikireg02@govreports.com.au");
            driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("Viki2607");
            driver.findElement(By.id("ConfirmPassword")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("ConfirmPassword")).sendKeys("Viki2607");
            String capColorDropDown = "//span[@role='listbox']";
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(capColorDropDown)).click();
            String itemName = "Orange";
            String listId = "color_listbox";
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            String xpathForItem = "//ul[@id='Salutation_listbox']/li[@class='k-item' and text()='Mr']";
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathForItem)).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).sendKeys("Vignesh");
            driver.findElement(By.id("LastName")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("LastName")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("LastName")).sendKeys("Ks");
            driver.findElement(By.id("TelephoneAreaCode")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("TelephoneAreaCode")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("TelephoneAreaCode")).sendKeys("02");
            driver.findElement(By.id("TelephoneNumber")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("TelephoneNumber")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("TelephoneNumber")).sendKeys("2356895623");
            driver.findElement(By.id("AddressDetails_Line1")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("AddressDetails_Line1")).sendKeys("Walker Street");
```

//I got to select the city from the drop down values (auto complete text box) i have used this below line but it is not working for me

**`

```
driver.findElement(By.id("AddressDetails_City")).click();`
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(tagText));
                WebElement textBoxElement = driver.findElement(tagText);
                textBoxElement.sendKeys("sydn");
                selectOptionWithText("SYDNEY, NSW, Australia, 1001");
                //selectOptionWithIndex(0);**
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                driver.findElement(By.linkText("Next")).click();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
    }


      private void selectOptionWithIndex(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void selectOptionWithText(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
          fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
      }

      private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
          driver.findElement(by);
          return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      private boolean isAlertPresent() {
        try {
          driver.switchTo().alert();
          return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
        try {
          Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
          String alertText = alert.getText();
          if (acceptNextAlert) {
            alert.accept();
          } else {
            alert.dismiss();
          }
          return alertText;
        } finally {
          acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

I can't able to fill the city, state, postal code and country fields in the address section. I can't able to access the auto complete values in those fields. I have highlighted the problem area with ** symbol in the script.

I think the website is publicly accessible. Can someone help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you comment down the url separately because the url which you have mentioned in your script is saying 'logging out because of inactivity'.

Comment: Can u plz give a try now with updated script in question.I have changed the baseUrl in the script as http://govreports.com.au/dev/taxagentt1.html

Comment: I just had a walk through of your script, can you please tell me the exact thing which you are expecting from your script because no comments and all has been given i'm unable to get the expected outcome.

Comment: I separated the script into two, I need to select the city fields from the auto complete drop down. I have divided and showed the exact line where i used the particular comment. But it is not working for me. Please suggest some solution to get city field from drop down.

Comment: can you give the url of the required page where this city object is present.

Comment: https://t1accounts.govreports.com.au/Account/Registration?key=AGNO_17470002|Name_Viki%20Ks|PK_SAVVY|&userType=TAXAgent&membershipType=GovReports&QBOkey=

Comment: Locality name field in the billing address section is the city drop down box.